# ABS(A) and abs(int)

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, function, macros

I am baffled in the difference of this two in xcode, ABS(A) and abs(int). Cant seem to find ay explanation online as well. Which should I use? I am actually working on an accelerometer. Using ABS(A) and abs(int) gives me two different values. Using abs(int) would result in an inf value at times, while ABS(A) would give me a different value but never inf. Thanks!

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/iphone-tutorial-reading-the-accelerometer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`abs()` works on int, meaning `abs(-10.123)` would return `10`, while `ABS()` is a macro from `NSObjCRuntime.h` which returns a value whose type is the type of the argument.

Comment: ahhhh. I see! THX! So am I right to say abs(int) would always return an integer?

Answer (score 6):

The ABS definition from NSObjCRuntime.h is :

```
#define ABS(a) ({typeof(a) _a = (a); _a < 0 ? -_a : _a; })
```

so it returns the value with the type of the argument.
abs on the other hand has the protoype

```
int abs (int number)
```

so it returns a value of type int.

Answer (score 3):

`ABS()` is most likely a macro, meaning it's a copy-pasta of some code into your application, whilst `abs()` is probably a function. In most situations, use the function, as it has no odd reprocussions should you include an assignment in there.

Answer (score 0):

A word of warning about using macros with arguments which are functions, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BAD_ABS(A) ((A)<0 ? (-(A)):(A))
int     afunc(){
    printf("afunc was called\n");
    return 1;
}
int     main(void){
    int     a;
    a = BAD_ABS(afunc());
    /* this has the result of:
    a = (afunc()<0) ? (-(afunc())) : (afunc());
    */
}
```

The function 'afunc' will be called twice, first for the comparison <0 and second when it returns the result -A or A.

The way the ABS macro in NSObjCRuntime.h is defined avoids this by introducing an extra variable, but some DIY macros might not, e.g. I have seen in several places

```
 #define BAD_ABS(a) ((a)<0 ? (-(a)) : (a))
```

It gets worse if the function to be called is a random number generator, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){
   short seeds[] = {1,2,3};
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<10000;i++) printf("%ld\n", BAD_ABS(jrand48(seeds)));
}
```

this has a 50-50 chance of returning a negative number!!!

If on the other hand you want to use the stdlib abs() function then be warned that it will not work with long integers. In that case you should use labs().

Answer (score -1):

We have two choices for

```
#define ABS(a) ({typeof(a) _a = (a); _a < 0 ? -_a : _a; })
```

in Swift 2 use

```
Int32 abs(Int32) which has a return type Int32
T abs(T) which has a return type T where T is a generic type
```

I hope it works, Thanks

Comment: The question is tagged ObjectiveC, you're providing an answer in Swift.

Comment: Ofcourse the question is tagged in Objective C, But it is useful in Swift right.. AnyWays thanks for down Vote but the people can use my Answer in swift

Comment: Correct, but your answer is still out of place as it's not relevant to the question.